# Boolean algebras and rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, boolean-algebra

I know that M. H. Stone proved that there is a bijection between boolean algebras and boolean rings. The bijection I know is the following: to any given Boolen algebra $(L,\, \vee, \wedge)$ we associate the ring with addition and mutiplication given by the following relations: $$x+y:=(x\wedge y')\vee (x'\wedge y)$$ where the $x'$ is the complement of $x$; $$xy=x\wedge y.$$

Anyway trying to prove that relation I find that starting with $(L, \vee, \wedge)$ it is possible to define the respective ring without the absorption laws. Is it true or have I necesserily made some mistake in the proof?

Comment: You get that it's a ring, not necessarily a boolean ring.

Comment: Why? The idempotence of its elements follows from the fact that $x\wedge x=x$.

Comment: There is also the unit since a Boolean algebra has the maximum $x\wedge 1=x$.

Comment: You need absorption to prove $x \wedge x = x$, don't you?

Comment: My textbook says that the laws of a Boolean algebra are the following (with duals):

$a\vee a=a$, commutativity/associativity of $\vee$, distributivity, absorption.

Comment: Is it possible to prove from $a\vee a=a$ and the others, the absorption?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Question from the comments which is in some sense the point of the original question): Is it possible to prove absorption from "$a \wedge a = a$" and the others? Yes:

Lemma 1: for all $a$, $a \wedge 0 = 0$.

$a \wedge \neg a  = 0$ (complement)

$a \wedge a \wedge \neg a = 0$ ($a \wedge a = a$)

$a \wedge 0 = 0$ (complement)

Lemma 2: $a \wedge (a \vee b) =  a$ (i.e absorption one way round)

$(a \vee 0) \wedge (a \vee b) = a \vee (0 \wedge b)$ (distributivity)

$a \wedge (a \vee b) = a \vee 0$ (identity, Lemma 1, and commutativity)

$a \wedge (a \vee b) = a$ (identity)

The other absorption axiom is $a \vee (a \wedge b) = a$. We prove this:

$a \wedge (a \vee b) = (a \wedge a) \vee (a \wedge b)$ (distributivity)

$a = a \vee (a \wedge b)$ (Lemma 2 and $a \wedge a = a$)